# Is it possible to split (or move) a git repository between directories?

Tags: git

When working on a home project, I decided to keep one common git repository for two close areas of the project: `hello` and `world`, each being developed in its own directory:

```
$ ls -la
.git hello world
```

I now realize that this was a mistake and that I should have split it into two repositories, one in each directory.

**Best case scenario**: is there a mechanism which splits a repository in two, moving the changes relevant to files in `hello` and in `world` to their respective repositories (one in `hello` and one in `world`)

**Less good case scenario**: I care somehow less about the history in `world` so is there a way to move the whole repository into `hello` (it would also cover changes in `world` but never mind) so that I can restart a fresh repo in `world`?

**Even less good case scenario** (but who know): I will restart the repos from scratch and call it a lesson learned in thinking ahead more than I thought I should.

Comment: Yup, with filter-branch and a combination of `--prune-empty` and `--subdirectory-filter` - see https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository

Comment: @1615903: thanks, the other comment points to an exact duplicate which I will mark as such

Comment: @FrancJnr: thanks! this is a duplicate I will mark as such